# How can I properly convert a list's output values to use them as args inside a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to write a script in python which searches the screen for a specific color in RGB, gets the pixel coordinates and then sends those to a click function to click on it. Here's my code so far:

```py
from PIL import ImageGrab
import win32api, win32con

def click(x,y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,x,y,0,0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,x,y,0,0)

color = (10,196,182)
session = False
match = False

while(True):
    screen = ImageGrab.grab()
    found_pixels = []
    for i, pixel in enumerate(screen.getdata()):
        if pixel == color:
            match = True
            found_pixels.append(i)
            break
    else:
        match = False

    width, height = screen.size
    found_pixels_coords = [divmod(index, width) for index in found_pixels]

    if session == False and match == True:
        click(found_pixels_coords)
        print("Match_Found")
        session = True
    if session == True and match == False:
        session = False
```

How can I convert the output of `founds_pixels_coords` to use it inside the `click(x,y)` function? I'm also getting the output values reversed, `(y,x)` instead of `(x,y)`, which I don't understand why.

Here's my console output, in case I'm totally wrong:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 28, in <module>
    click(found_pixels_coords)
TypeError: click() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

**EDIT:**
 `click(*found_pixels_coords[0])` as suggested by @martineau seems to solve the missing argument error. I also got around the reversed values by defining  `click(y,x)` . Any proper solution to this however, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `click(*found_pixels_coords)`?

Comment: @Mark Meyer Yes, I tried that, but it didn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `found_pixels_coords` is a list (although it will never contain more than one set of coordindates), here's how to use the one set in it (if any matched):

```
    .
    .
    .
    if session == False and match == True:
        click(*found_pixels_coords[0]) # <== Do it like this.
        print("Match_Found")
        session = True
    if session == True and match == False:
        session = False
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: Hello, this seems to work, I got no error this time and the mouse moved, however it didn't move to the correct pixel, which makes me think it is because of the reversed values.

Comment: @WutwutBoody: That's certainly possible and may be a result of the `divmod()` logic you're using to create the `found_pixels_coords` list.I didn't verify that part because it's not the topic of your question. Regardless, now that you know how extract the coordinates, you should be able to debug this other issue. Also note it's fairly common for image pixels to be addressed by (y, x) instead of (x, y) because of how image data is stored in computer memory. Since my answer addresses your original question, please consider accepting it.

Comment: P.S. I don't know what other uses you may be making of the `match` (and  `session`) variables, but in Python you can can check to see if anything is in a `list` by using `if found_pixels_coords: ...` because the "truthiness" of a non-empty list is considered `True`.

Comment: Looked into your issue some more, I've discovered that the color values returned by `image.getdata()` don't match those returned by [`image.getpixel()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.getpixel) for the same pixel location. May be a bug in the PIL. To work-around it use `getpixel()`, and if the color matches, you can pass the same `(x, y)` coordinates used with it to the `win32api.SetCursorPos()` function directly. It problem seems to have something to do with the Windows Taskbar offsetting pixel data in `ImageGrab.grab()` image retrieved.

Comment: Maybe it's because `getdata()` returns the pixel indexes, that's why I later use `divmod()` to get the `x,y` coordinates. I use `getdata()` because it's faster than `getpixel()` for my use case. Thanks for the info again!

Comment: No, `getdata()` doesn't return indices, it returns pixel data. Your code effectively creates them through its use of `enumerate()`.

Answer (score 1):

Just call `click()` like this (add a `*` before the list name to unpack the values).

```
click(*found_pixels_coords)  # Make sure list contains 2 values
```

If you are not sure about number of items in `found_pixels_coords` list then just change the signature of `click()` function from

```
def click(x, y):
```

to

```
def click(x, y, *args):
```

In this case, if there will be more than 2 values in list, no problem, 3 to onwards will be in `args` tuple.

Answer (score 0):

As you say that the order of the coordinates is inverted, we can use two auxiliary variables to unpack the values and then pass them in the required order:

```
y, x = found_pixels_coords
click(x, y)
```

If `found_pixels_coords` is a list with several coordinates, then you can pick the first one with:

```
y, x = found_pixels_coords[0]
click(x, y)
```

Comment: Hello, I also tried that but I got the following `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)` .

Comment: what do you get if you add `print(found_pixels_coords)` statement before that? seems the value is `None`

Comment: `found_pixels_coords` must be an empty list.

Comment: @javalvo Hello, I get the pixel coordinates of the specified color, but reversed. The format looks like this: `(538, 600)` .

Comment: While this may answer the question, code only answers are generally regarded as lo-quality. Providing some more description and context on why will improve the quality of this answer. Thanks.

Comment: I've extended the reply, thanks for the suggestion.